# jQuery find same td in prev. and next row

Tags: jquery, css, click

I have a table and I know how to search next and prev `TD`, but how to do it on the next and previous `TR`?

```
012
345 <- example, I clicked on 4, it checks 3 and 5, but how to check on 0,1,2 and 6,7,8?
678
```

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("td").click(function() {

        var x = $(this).next().css('backgroundColor');
        var y = $(this).prev().css('backgroundColor');

        if (x == 'rgb(255, 0, 0)' || y == 'rgb(255, 0, 0)') {
            return;
        } else {
            $(this).css('backgroundColor', 'red');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: not sure but try `$(this).parent().prev()`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I made some research and came up with a working solution that works. Thanks all for help:

```
$(this).parent().next().find('td').eq($(this).index()-1).css('backgroundColor');
```

Comment: Becareful, this won't work as expected if `rowspan` or `colspan` is being used in any `tr/td` that comes before the one you are looking for.

Comment: That `-1` is wrong because both [`.eq()`](https://api.jquery.com/eq/) and [`.index()`](https://api.jquery.com/index/) are 0-based.

Answer (score 4):

Use `parent()` method on `td` to go to `tr` and then you can use `prev()` or `next()` accordingly.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("td").click(function() {

        var $tr = $(this).parent();//this will give the tr
        $tr.prev();//previous tr 
        $tr.next();//next tr 

        //To get the corresponding td's in the next and prev rows
        var tdIndex = $(this).index();

        $tr.prev().find("td:not(:eq(" + tdIndex + "))");
        $tr.next().find("td:not(:eq(" + tdIndex + "))");

    });
});
```

Comment: Yes, i know how to find the next and prev. row, but how do i check the same click position up and down? That's the real problem. '$(this).parent('tr').next().(this).css('backgroundColor');' not working, im new to jQuery, don't understand it so well yet. I need the same click position on the other rows.

Comment: `$(this).parent('tr').next().(this).css('backgroundColor')` is wrong.

Comment: Do you want to find the corresponding td in the prev and next rows?

Answer (score 3):

Something like `$(this).closest('tr').next('tr').find('td')` will get you all the `<td>`s within the row after the one containing the `<td>` your event fired on.

Answer (score 2):

check out `.parent()` in jquery..

Answer (score 2):

```
$(this).parent('tr').next()
```

and

```
$(this).parent('tr').prev()
```

Answer (score 2):

Try with parent ;) http://api.jquery.com/parent/