# jQuery - Find Next Number in Previous Row of Look-up Table

Tags: jquery, lookup-tables

This is a follow-up question to the one answered here - [jQuery - Find Value Based on Input and Lookup Table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13525764/jquery-find-value-based-on-input-and-lookup-table).

That solution worked perfectly. There's one outstanding issue though.

The look-up table contains dashes, and I need numbers for subsequent calculations. So what I want to do is (1) after locating the proper td, (2) I'd like to confirm that it's a number, (3) if so, use it, and (4) if not, go up to the previous rows in the same column until a number is found. (5) If one is found, stop checking. (6) If no number is found, I'll display a message.

Here's how far I've gotten:

```
jQuery.fn.reverse = [].reverse;

function GetTableValue(column, value, table) {
    var smallestdiff = 0;
    var savedindex = 0;

    $(table).find('td:first-child').reverse().each(function(i) {
        diff = parseFloat($(this).text(),10) - value;
        if (diff >= smallestdiff) {
            smallestdiff = diff;
            savedindex = 12 - i;
            return false;
        }
    });

    tr = $(table).find('tr:eq('+ savedindex +')');
    $(".scc-round").val( tr.find('td:first-child').text() );

    var cell_value = tr.find('td:nth-child('+ column +')').text();

    if( isNaN(cell_value) ) {
        savedindex = savedindex - 1;
    }

    // this is as far as I've gotten

    new_ie_value = tr.find('td:nth-child('+ column +')').text();
}
```

Example: So using the table below, if the number is one (at or less than 5), and the column is one (go over 1 column), I would get "-". I want to go up to the next number, which would be "0.6".

My approach was to subtract from the value of the row (savedindex) and traverse upwards, but I'm not sure how to write it. Furthermore, I ended having a ton of coding that I'm sure could be simplified.

Example Table:

```
<table id="ms25">
    <tr>
        <td>20</td>
        <td>-</td>
        <td>-</td>
        <td>-</td>
        <td>-</td>
        <td>-</td>
        <td>4.6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>15</td>
        <td>1.2</td>
        <td>1.2</td>
        <td>0.8</td>
        <td>0.8</td>
        <td>0.6</td>
        <td>3.5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>10</td>
        <td>0.8</td>
        <td>0.8</td>
        <td>0.5</td>
        <td>0.5</td>
        <td>0.4</td>
        <td>2.3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>7.5</td>
        <td>0.6</td>
        <td>0.6</td>
        <td>0.4</td>
        <td>0.4</td>
        <td>0.3</td>
        <td>1.8</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>-</td>
        <td>-</td>
        <td>-</td>
        <td>-</td>
        <td>-</td>
        <td>1.2</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Help/direction would be appreciated.

Thanks.

-Stephen

UPDATE:

I came up with a solution. Posting my solution just in case it can help others.

```
function GetTableValue(column, value, table) {
    smallestdiff = Number.MAX_VALUE;
    var savedindex = 0;

    $(table).find('td:first-child').each(function(i) {
        diff = parseInt($(this).text(),10) - parseInt(value, 10);
        if (diff >= 0 && diff < smallestdiff) {
            smallestdiff = diff;
            savedindex = i;
        }
    });

    tr = $(table).find('tr:eq('+ savedindex +')');
    $(".scc-round").val( tr.find('td:first-child').text() );
    new_ie_value = tr.find('td:nth-child('+ column +')').text();

    // only a few are not numbers, so i'll do a quick check
    if(isNaN(parseFloat(new_ie_value, 10))) {
            $(table).find('tr').each(function(i){
                if(isNaN(parseFloat(new_ie_value, 10))) {
                savedindex = savedindex - 1;
            }
            tr = $(table).find('tr:eq('+ savedindex +')');
            $(".scc-round").val( tr.find('td:first-child').text() );
            new_ie_value = tr.find('td:nth-child('+ column +')').text();
        });
    }

    // it's possible that the top td is still not a number
    if(isNaN(parseFloat(new_ie_value, 10))) {
        $(".scc-round").val("call");
    }
}
```

I'm sure this could be more efficient, but it works.

Comment: Your description of the problem doesn't seem to be consistent with the example. There's no hyphen in column 1 of any row, they're all in column 7.

Comment: Yikes! Sorry about that. I don't even see in my code where I got those numbers. Sleep deprived posting does that. I'll be more careful.